# replace every word in a file with the value from another dictionary file

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a text file mytext.txt, each line of the text is a sentence:

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
colorless green ideas sleep furiously
```

Then I have a dictionary file dict.txt like this:

```
the: A
quick: B
brown: C
fox: D
jumps: E
over: F
lazy: G
dog: H
colorless: I
green: J
ideas: K
sleep: L
furiously: M
```

I want to replace each word in mytext.txt with the value in dict.txt, like this:

```
A B C D E F A G H
I J K L M
```

How can I do it using awk or sed?

Comment: This is probably much simpler in any scripting language.

Comment: I've voted to close this question because it appears to be a request for a recommendation for a tool or solution, rather than a request for assistance with your own code. This makes your question off-topic for StackOverflow. If that assessment was incorrect, and you do indeed want help writing your own code, then please [add your work so far to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42983982/edit) and I'll retract my close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[: ]' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$NF;next}{for(i in a)gsub(i,a[i])}1' dist mytext
```

**OR**

```
$ awk -F'[: ]' 'FNR==NR{ a[$1]=$NF; next }
  { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i in a)$i=a[$i] }1' dist mytext
```

**Input**

```
$ cat mytext 
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
colorless green ideas sleep furiously

$ cat dist 
the: A
quick: B
brown: C
fox: D
jumps: E
over: F
lazy: G
dog: H
colorless: I
green: J
ideas: K
sleep: L
furiously: M
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F'[: ]' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$NF;next}{for(i in a)gsub(i,a[i])}1' dist mytext 
A B C D E F A G H
I J K L M

$ awk -F'[: ]' 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$NF; next}
{ for(i=1; i<=NF;i++) if($i in a)$i=a[$i] }1' dist mytext 
A B C D E F A G H
I J K L M
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you! Although my dictionary contains some keys with multiple values (the: A; the: AA), and this code only matches the last one.

Comment: @drstar: true because `the`:`AA` is found last while reading first file

Answer (score 1):

If your dict.txt does not have any special chars, a very fast solution is to convert the content of dict.txt into a sed expresion:

```
sed 's#^#s/#;s#: #/#;s#$#/g;#' dict.txt
```

will result in

```
s/the/A/g;
s/quick/B/g;
s/brown/C/g;
s/fox/D/g;
s/jumps/E/g;
s/over/F/g;
s/lazy/G/g;
s/dog/H/g;
s/colorless/I/g;
s/green/J/g;
s/ideas/K/g;
s/sleep/L/g;
s/furiously/M/g;
```

now this can be used for another sed:

```
sed -f <(sed 's#^#s/#;s#: #/#;s#$#/g;#' dict.txt) mytext.txt
```

output:

```
A B C D E F A G H
I J K L M
```

But be aware if the dict file contains any characters special to sed `/` `\` `.` `*` a.s.o. it wount work

Edit: added the `g` to sed

Update:

If only whole words should be replaced this will do the trick, because `\b` will look for word boundarys:

```
sed -f <(sed 's#^#s/\\b#;s#: #\\b/#;s#$#/g;#' dict.txt) mytext.txt
```

thx @jm666 for pointing this out.

Edit2:

If the dict.txt file is very long my original version might fail. 
The version of @SLePort fixed this, thx. 
I previously used `"$()"` instead of `-f <()`

Comment: Nice out of the box thinking. ;) but, what about: `over the lazy dog themselves` and the `dict` will also contain `themselves: T`? need sort the `s///` statements from the longest to shortest or use the `\bword\b`.

Comment: @jm666: good point, depends on what the expected behaviour is for it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Or maybe using process substitution : `sed -f <(sed 's#^#s/#;s#: #/#;s#$#/g;#' dict.txt) mytext.txt`

Comment: drstar: the version of @SLePort should fix that error

Answer (score 0):

here is another alternative with `awk` and `sed`

```
$ sed -f <(awk -F': ' '{print "s/\\b" $1 "\\b/" $2 "/g"}' dict) file

A B C D E F A G H
I J K L M
```